# How to implement the Context API with a dynamic number of states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

The number of components in the array `listOfComponents` should be dynamic. In my application components get added and removed over time while the application is running. When I add a new component, I want to add a state for it inside the `listOfComponents` array in my `ExampleContext`. When I remove a component I want to remove the state. The component should only rerender if the settings in the `listOfComponents` get updated where the ids match. How would I go about implementing this?

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const ExampleContext = createContext()
export const { Consumer: ExampleConsumer } = ExampleContext

export function ExampleProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    listOfComponents: [{
        id: 1,
        settings: {color: 'red'}
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        settings: {color: 'blue'}
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        settings: {color: 'green'}
    }]
 })
  return (
    <ExampleContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {children}
    </ExampleContext.Provider>
  )
}

export function Component({id}) {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(ExampleContext)
  return (
    <h1> Only rerender me if settings of matching id are updated! </h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: I made a couple comments before but then I realized I don't quite know what you mean when you say 'states'. Is there any way you can make a small example? Because I'm pretty sure that, if used correctly, changing one small bit of the context shouldn't force every component to re-render

Comment: Read [this guide](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/react-context-performance/) on how to not have context re-rendering even after very small changes

Comment: @TKoL Under states I understand the use of the state hook like so `const [state, setState] = useState({})`. Only the components which use a state out of the Context API which gets updated will rerender. So I guess my problem is more searching of a way to implement a dynamic number of those useState hooks and use those in a dynamic number of components. Or a way to only update a component if a part of a useState is updated but not the whole.

Comment: @TKoL I updated my question so I hope its easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I made it work with `useMemo`. Maybe it is helpful for somebody else since it took me some time to figure it out. Also [this](https://blog.axlight.com/posts/4-options-to-prevent-extra-rerenders-with-react-context/) blog post was pretty helpful. If there is any better way please let me know.

-- App.js

```
import React, {useContext, useMemo} from 'react';
import {ExampleContext, ExampleProvider} from './Context'

export function Component({id}){
  const [state, setState] = useContext(ExampleContext)

  function onClick(){
    setState(prev => {
      return {...prev, [id]: { color: 'blue'}}
    })
  }

  return useMemo(() => {
    console.log(`update ${id}`)
    return (
      <>
        <h1 style={{color: state[id].color}}>{id}</h1>
        <button onClick={onClick}>{`Update from ${id}`}</button>
      </>
    )
  }, [state[id]])
}

function App() {
  return (
    <ExampleProvider>
        <Component id={1}/>
        <Component id={2}/>
    </ExampleProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

-- Context.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const ExampleContext = createContext()
export const { Consumer: ExampleConsumer } = ExampleContext

export function ExampleProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    '1': {color: 'red'},
    '2': {color: 'green'},
  })
  return (
    <ExampleContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {children}
    </ExampleContext.Provider>
  )
}
```